# Creating Custom Roles for use on a WordPress Multi-site Instance?

Tags: plugins, multisite, permissions

We have a large site that consists of a number of smaller websites.  We are looking at replacing our current CMS with WordPress.

The only problem is that we need to create a custom role (kind of in between Editor and Administrator) and make it available to all sites in a multi-site network. I have looked at a couple of plugins that work well on a single site, but none seem to work on multi-site.

Any recommendations?  This is the closest thing I have found:

- [WPMU Roles and Capabilities Hacks Plugin](http://co-opmedia.org/2010/04/wpmu-roles-and-capabilities-hacks/)

Answer (score 1):

Justin Tadlock's Members plugin works on multisite:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/

Comment: Thanks, i am going to download it now and give it a try.

Comment: Ok, I have it working but I have to re-do everything on every site.  I am looking for a plugin that I can do at the master level and then cascade down to the sub-sites.